# Having trouble setting positions of buttons in python, tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to position the 'YES' and 'NO' buttons lower. If I set`row =` to different numbers it would kind of work, but every time I set `row =` the same number for both, it just brings them back to their original positions. May someone please explain why this happens?

Images

[`NO.grid(row = 3, column = 5)`,`YES.grid(row = 3, column = 7)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUYOf.png)

[`NO.grid(row = 9, column = 5)`, `YES.grid(row = 10, column = 7)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gk2FD.png)

[`NO.grid(row = 10, column = 7)`, `YES.grid(row = 10, column = 7)`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRo87.png)

```
#Intro
l = Label(win, text = "Welcome to a simple number game.\n Would you like to play?", font=('Snap ITC', 30), bg='yellow', fg='slateblue')
l.grid(row = 2, column = 5, columnspan=5)

#Play or not buttons(YES/NO)
NO = Button(win, text = 'NO', command=clicked, relief=RAISED, padx=30, pady=1 )
NO.config(bg='DodgerBlue2', fg='spring green', font=('Snap ITC', 10), bd=6)
NO.grid(row = 10, column = 5)
YES = Button(win, text = 'YES', command=clicked1, relief=RAISED, padx=30, pady=1)
YES.config(bg='DodgerBlue2', fg='spring green', font=('Snap ITC', 10), bd=6)
YES.grid(row = 10, column = 7)
```

Comment: What do you mean with `it just brings them back to their original positions`? What exactly is the difference between what you get and what you want? It might be easiest to explain this with pictures.

Comment: @fhdrsdg I have added some pictures

Comment: Thank you. However, you still haven't explained what the differences between your expected results and your actual results are.

Comment: @fhdrsdg I want to set the YES and NO buttons lower than it already is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid geometry manager thinks that a row which contains nothing has the size zero. But you can create a distance with padding:

```
NO.grid(row = 10, column = 5, pady=(20,0))
```

The padding specifys how many pixels you want between the top of the row and the widget. In this case I have specified `pady=(20,0)` which means 20 pixels on the top and 0 pixels on the bottom. If you want the same amount on both top and bottom you can write `pady=20`